# JVM crash log file

Tags: centos, java

I have a java application running as a daemon. Suddenly it stop working so I would like to know if jvm crash and where will the log file be dump? It can be either fedora or centos?

Answer (score 2):

If the JVM is crashing, it should leave the hs_err_pidXXXX.log in the directory it's run from. If you want to send it somewhere else, you can run java with -XX:ErrorFile=/path/to/file.

Comment: I ran this command find / -name *hs_err* found no file. So that means not jvm crash event is it or must I set it some where first?

Comment: Unless you're telling `java` not to write that file, that basically means that yes, JVM is not crashing. But that file will only be created if the JVM crashes - if your program has an uncaught error or otherwise crashes itself, you won't get a JVM error log.

Comment: Is there any way to check whether I am telling program not to write the JVM log file. Any place to check what is the settings like?

Comment: It would be in the arguments to `java`. Look at how you're running the daemon - do you pass any arguments to it like _ErrorFile_? If not, you're not telling it not to write the file.

Comment: no I do not pass any errofile so how to set it?

Comment: If you aren't seeing an errorfile, then the JVM isn't writing one. This means that the program is probably crashing on its own. Run the daemon so that its stderr gets written to a logfile - you should get a stack trace from an uncaught exception.

Comment: Yes I do a lot of try and catch and send out the trace to the yajsw log file which I am using as daemon service.

Comment: Is there any special stderr which I must capture is it?

Comment: Your search command should look like this: `find / -name hs_err\*`